# C: how to read a webpage

Tags: c, sockets, curl

I'm trying to open a connection to a webpage (e.g. www.google.com) via localhost, port 80.

How can I do this programatically in C? I want get all the HTML headers and not just the content ;(

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Hmm ... read [Beej's Guides to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try using a library like libcurl? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Basically, I have a HTTP request stored in a buffer. I want to apply this HTTP request to localhost and get the response. I'm looking around at how I can do this. Unfortunately, with libcurl, you need to give it a url, not a text HTTP request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some example code on how to do this with `libcurl`:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

There is another one right there, that shows you how to get some header data:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinfo.html

These examples and many others are available as part of the `libcurl` distribution. It should more than get you started.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with libcurl... Many thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Summarized process:

- DNS resolution for the hostname (using `getaddrinfo()`)
- Open a stream socket (TCP) to the resolved IP address and port
- Send GET request (see protocol in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

  GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.example.com
- Read headers - Terminated by \r\n\r\n
- Read body
- Close socket

Answer (score 0):

**Minimal runnable POSIX example**

In this answer, I provide a minimal runnable POSIX C example: [How to make an HTTP get request in C without libcurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208299/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-in-c-without-libcurl/35680609#35680609)

It allows you to do:

```
./wget example.com
```

to download http://example.com