# Simple C example of doing an HTTP POST and consuming the response

Tags: c, http, http-post

I would like to create a very simple C application that does an HTTP post.  It will take a few parameters, and use these to construct a URL.  I'd just like to do a simple HTTP POST and get the response without the use of curl (the libraries are not and will not be installed on the machine this needs to run).

Pseudo-code:

1. Process 2 args
2. Put args into template URL: http://api.somesite.com/apikey=ARG1&command=ARG2
3. Do POST on generated URL
4. Consume response

My Google and SO searches haven't yielded anything on this matter.

Comment: Do you use any kind of network framework ? What OS do you use ?

Comment: It'll be just a basic Fedora or Cent box.  The network frameworks are the usual sys/socket, netdb, arpa/inet.  Just not libcurl.

Comment: Not libcurl. Are you willing to go with any other library or does it have to be all-POSIX.

Comment: All POSIX unfortunately.  It has to be completely free standing on any system.

Comment: I have a sample I made for you but I don't understand why you are using POST if there is no body for the message.  If all the parameters are in the query string why don't you want to do a GET?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Do you mind posting your example?  The API documents all used POST, but were pretty lacking overall.  It's entirely possible GET could work.

Comment: how to give input..if i want the url -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315570/

Comment: Next time you face a similar problem you might also consider linking the library statically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP get Request using C WITHOUT libCurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208299/http-get-request-using-c-without-libcurl) Networking part is the same, only HTTP parsing differs.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

A message has a header part and a message body separated by a blank line.  The blank line is ALWAYS needed even if there is no message body.  The header starts with a command and has additional lines of key value pairs separated by a colon and a space.  If there is a message body, it can be anything you want it to be.

Lines in the header and the blank line at the end of the header must end with a carraige return and linefeed pair (see [HTTP header line break style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757290/http-header-line-break-style)) so that's why those lines have \r\n at the end.

A URL has the form of `http://host:port/path?query_string`

There are two main ways of submitting a request to a website:

- GET: The query string is optional but, if specified, must be reasonably short. Because of this the header could just be the GET command and nothing else. A sample message could be:

  ```
    GET /path?query_string HTTP/1.0\r\n
    \r\n
  ```
- POST: What would normally be in the query string is in the body of the message instead. Because of this the header needs to include the Content-Type: and Content-Length: attributes as well as the POST command.  A sample message could be:

  ```
    POST /path HTTP/1.0\r\n
    Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
    Content-Length: 12\r\n
    \r\n
    query_string
  ```

So, to answer your question: if the URL you are interested in POSTing to is http://api.somesite.com/apikey=ARG1&command=ARG2 then there is no body or query string and, consequently, no reason to POST because there is nothing to put in the body of the message and so nothing to put in the Content-Type: and Content-Length:

I guess you could POST if you really wanted to.  In that case your message would look like:

```
POST /apikey=ARG1&command=ARG2 HTTP/1.0\r\n
\r\n
```

So to send the message the C program needs to:

- create a socket
- lookup the IP address
- open the socket
- send the request
- wait for the response
- close the socket

The send and receive calls won't necessarily send/receive ALL the data you give them - they will return the number of bytes actually sent/received.  It is up to you to call them in a loop and send/receive the remainder of the message.

What I did not do in this sample is any sort of real error checking - when something fails I just exit the program.  Let me know if it works for you:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    /* first what are we going to send and where are we going to send it? */
    int portno =        80;
    char *host =        "api.somesite.com";
    char *message_fmt = "POST /apikey=%s&command=%s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total;
    char message[1024],response[4096];

    if (argc < 3) { puts("Parameters: <apikey> <command>"); exit(0); }

    /* fill in the parameters */
    sprintf(message,message_fmt,argv[1],argv[2]);
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    /* send the request */
    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);

    /* receive the response */
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response+received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while (received < total);

    /*
     * if the number of received bytes is the total size of the
     * array then we have run out of space to store the response
     * and it hasn't all arrived yet - so that's a bad thing
     */
    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* process response */
    printf("Response:\n%s\n",response);

    return 0;
}
```

Like the other answer pointed out, 4096 bytes is not a very big response.  I picked that number at random assuming that the response to your request would be short.  If it can be big you have two choices:

- read the Content-Length: header from the response and then dynamically allocate enough memory to hold the whole response.
- write the response to a file as the pieces arrive

Additional information to answer the question asked in the comments:

What if you want to POST data in the body of the message?  Then you do need to include the Content-Type: and Content-Length: headers.  The Content-Length: is the actual length of everything after the blank line that separates the header from the body.

Here is a sample that takes the following command line arguments:

- host
- port
- command (GET or POST)
- path (not including the query data)
- query data (put into the query string for GET and into the body for POST)
- list of headers (Content-Length: is automatic if using POST)

So, for the original question you would run:

```
a.out api.somesite.com 80 GET "/apikey=ARG1&command=ARG2"
```

And for the question asked in the comments you would run:

```
a.out api.somesite.com 80 POST / "name=ARG1&value=ARG2" "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit, atoi, malloc, free */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    
    /* first where are we going to send it? */
    int portno = atoi(argv[2])>0?atoi(argv[2]):80;
    char *host = strlen(argv[1])>0?argv[1]:"localhost";

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total, message_size;
    char *message, response[4096];

    if (argc < 5) { puts("Parameters: <host> <port> <method> <path> [<data> [<headers>]]"); exit(0); }

    /* How big is the message? */
    message_size=0;
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\n");        /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                         /* path           */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[4]);                         /* headers        */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                     /* query string   */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
    }
    else
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                         /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[4]);                         /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen("Content-Length: %lu\r\n")+20; /* content length */
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                     /* body           */
    }
    
    /* allocate space for the message */
    message=malloc(message_size);
    
    /* fill in the parameters */
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message,"%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",               /* method         */
                strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/",                 /* path           */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?"?":"",                      /* ?              */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?argv[5]:"");                 /* query string   */
        else
            sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",               /* method         */
                strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/");                /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
            strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"POST",                  /* method         */
            strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/");                    /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Content-Length: %lu\r\n",strlen(argv[5]));
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */
        if(argc>5)
            strcat(message,argv[5]);                           /* body           */
    }

    /* What are we going to send? */
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    /* send the request */
    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);

    /* receive the response */
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response+received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while (received < total);

    /*
     * if the number of received bytes is the total size of the
     * array then we have run out of space to store the response
     * and it hasn't all arrived yet - so that's a bad thing
     */
    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* process response */
    printf("Response:\n%s\n",response);

    free(message);
    return 0;
}
```

And, as asked in the comments, here is a HTTP/1.1 version:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit, atoi, malloc, free */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    
    /* first where are we going to send it? */
    int portno = atoi(argv[2])>0?atoi(argv[2]):80;
    char *host = strlen(argv[1])>0?argv[1]:"localhost";

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total, message_size;
    char *message, response[4096];

    if (argc < 5) { puts("Parameters: <host> <port> <method> <path> [<data> [<headers>]]"); exit(0); }

    /* How big is the message? */
    message_size=0;
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.1\r\n");           /* method            */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                            /* path              */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[4]);                            /* headers           */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                        /* query string      */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                       /* headers           */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen("Host: %s\r\n");                     /* host header       */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[1]);                            /* host              */
        message_size+=strlen("Connection: close\r\n");            /* connection header */
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                             /* blank line        */
    }
    else
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                            /* method            */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[4]);                            /* path              */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                       /* headers           */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen("Host: %s\r\n");                     /* host header       */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[1]);                            /* host              */
        message_size+=strlen("Connection: close\r\n");            /* connection header */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen("Content-Length: %lu\r\n")+20;   /* content length    */
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                             /* blank line        */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                        /* body              */
    }
    
    /* allocate space for the message */
    message=malloc(message_size);
    
    /* fill in the parameters */
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message,"%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.1\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",                  /* method            */
                strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/",                    /* path              */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?"?":"",                         /* ?                 */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?argv[5]:"");                    /* query string      */
        else
            sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",                  /* method            */
                strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/");                   /* path              */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                       /* headers           */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Host: %s\r\n",           /* host header       */
            argv[1]);                                             /* host              */
        sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Connection: close\r\n"); /* connection header */
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                   /* blank line        */
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n",
            strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"POST",                     /* method            */
            strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/");                       /* path              */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                       /* headers           */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Host: %s\r\n",           /* host header       */
            argv[1]);                                             /* host              */
        sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Connection: close\r\n"); /* connection header */
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Content-Length: %lu\r\n",strlen(argv[5]));
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                   /* blank line        */
        if(argc>5)
            strcat(message,argv[5]);                              /* body              */
    }

    /* What are we going to send? */
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    /* send the request */
    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);

    /* receive the response */
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response+received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while (received < total);

    /*
     * if the number of received bytes is the total size of the
     * array then we have run out of space to store the response
     * and it hasn't all arrived yet - so that's a bad thing
     */
    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* process response */
    printf("Response:\n%s\n",response);

    free(message);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What arguments should be passed when called?

Comment: You need to pass something that will be used as an apikey as the first parameter and something in the second parameter that will be used as the command. If you want to use a completely different query string then you need to change the format string, the number of parameters and the usage message.

Comment: This code emits a malformed HTTP request.  HTTP specifies that request lines must be terminated by carriage-return/line-feed pairs (`\r\n`), but this code uses bare line feeds.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's very true.  Thanks for pointing it out.  Hopefully the edited answer is better.

Comment: What's wrong with this post message? `"POST /variableName=%s&value=%s HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 4\r\n\r\n\r\n"` I want to post like name=reaz. It responds 400 Bad Request

Comment: @ReazMurshed in a POST the query string data is in the body. If you want it at the top you need to use a GET and separate the page from the query string with a ?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Many thanks for your comment. Let me explain my scenario. I need to post some data in a server which takes only application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type. How this can be achieved? And how can I determine the content length? Does it necessary? Say for example I want to post a data like "name" = "reaz". Many thanks for your concern.

Comment: @ReazMurshed I have added some more info to my answer.  You want to send something of this form: `"POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 9\r\n\r\nname=reaz"`

Comment: I was happy to find this post! It helped me a lot but I had an issue with multiple sends and receives... it seems like after my first successful send and receive... my 2nd send goes thru but the receive never comes back...

Comment: Not sure why the code is not working for me. I'm doing a GET request to the server, basically `GET /apis/vi/deviceIdGenerate HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n` and the server is supposed to return JSON string. I've tried `... HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n` as well. It is a HTTPS secure site, does that have anything to do with it. I get sometimes `ERROR reading response from socket: Connection reset by peer` or `Response: 

` where it is completely empty. Can anyone help me? and I guess a **NOTE** is that curl works for the request.

Comment: @nf071590 HTTPS is completely different.  You need to ask that as a new question.

Comment: I want to mention that in most cases, you must specify the HOST in request to make this program work.
For those who don't know this:  Chrome(browser) will add HOST(the website you input) in header for you, so you can access it. But you can't visit the IP of that website because it will fill the HOST with your input IP.

Comment: @YongHaoHu  I never had a website require the Host header so I didn't mention it.  But then I discovered that when sending SOAP requests the Host header and the SOAPAction header are both needed - I just assumed that Host was a SOAP thing.  So thanks for that bit of info.

Comment: A good link for the HTTP Message spec: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Given how utterly amazing this answer is, may I ask if you could add a POST example for http 1.1? I ask because 1.0 doesn't require the host header but I think 1.1 does?

Comment: @intrigued_66 Shall I just update the examples to 1.1? Or should I add more examples?

Answer (score 25):

After weeks of research. I came up with the following code. I believe this is the bare minimum needed to make a secure connection with SSL to a web server.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

#define APIKEY "YOUR_API_KEY"
#define HOST "YOUR_WEB_SERVER_URI"
#define PORT "443"

int main() {

    //
    //  Initialize the variables
    //
    BIO* bio;
    SSL* ssl;
    SSL_CTX* ctx;

    //
    //   Registers the SSL/TLS ciphers and digests.
    //
    //   Basically start the security layer.
    //
    SSL_library_init();

    //
    //  Creates a new SSL_CTX object as a framework to establish TLS/SSL
    //  or DTLS enabled connections
    //
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

    //
    //  -> Error check
    //
    if (ctx == NULL)
    {
        printf("Ctx is null\n");
    }

    //
    //   Creates a new BIO chain consisting of an SSL BIO
    //
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);

    //
    //  Use the variable from the beginning of the file to create a 
    //  string that contains the URL to the site that you want to connect
    //  to while also specifying the port.
    //
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, HOST ":" PORT);

    //
    //   Attempts to connect the supplied BIO
    //
    if(BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0)
    {
        printf("Failed connection\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Connected\n");
    }

    //
    //  The bare minimum to make a HTTP request.
    //
    char* write_buf = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                      "Host: " HOST "\r\n"
                      "Authorization: Basic " APIKEY "\r\n"
                      "Connection: close\r\n"
                      "\r\n";

    //
    //   Attempts to write len bytes from buf to BIO
    //
    if(BIO_write(bio, write_buf, strlen(write_buf)) <= 0)
    {
        //
        //  Handle failed writes here
        //
        if(!BIO_should_retry(bio))
        {
            // Not worth implementing, but worth knowing.
        }

        //
        //  -> Let us know about the failed writes
        //
        printf("Failed write\n");
    }

    //
    //  Variables used to read the response from the server
    //
    int size;
    char buf[1024];

    //
    //  Read the response message
    //
    for(;;)
    {
        //
        //  Get chunks of the response 1023 at the time.
        //
        size = BIO_read(bio, buf, 1023);

        //
        //  If no more data, then exit the loop
        //
        if(size <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        //
        //  Terminate the string with a 0, to let know C when the string 
        //  ends.
        //
        buf[size] = 0;

        //
        //  ->  Print out the response
        //
        printf("%s", buf);
    }

    //
    //  Clean after ourselves
    //
    BIO_free_all(bio);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above will explain in details how to establish a TLS connection with a remote server.

**Important note**: this code doesn't check if the public key was signed by a valid authority. Meaning I don't use root certificates for validation. Don't forget to implement this check otherwise you won't know if you are connecting the right website

When it comes to the request itself. It is nothing more then writing the HTTP request by hand.

You can also find under this [link](https://github.com/davidgatti/What-Is-My-IP/tree/master/client-cli) an explanation how to instal openSSL in your system, and how to compile the code so it uses the [secure library](https://github.com/davidgatti/What-Is-My-IP/tree/master/client-cli).

Comment: Nice Explanation !

Answer (score 14):

Jerry's answer is great. However, it doesn't handle large responses. A simple change to handle this:

```
memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
total = sizeof(response)-1;
received = 0;
do {
    printf("RESPONSE: %s\n", response);
    // HANDLE RESPONSE CHUCK HERE BY, FOR EXAMPLE, SAVING TO A FILE.
    memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
    bytes = recv(sockfd, response, 1024, 0);
    if (bytes < 0)
        printf("ERROR reading response from socket");
    if (bytes == 0)
        break;
    received+=bytes;
} while (1);
```

Comment: You could just make the response array in my example larger. I was assuming he was just getting back some json and wasn't downloading a huge file but of course even json can be megabytes depending on the query...

Comment: I'm a C beginner and your answer might be correct. But can you please add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: This is really just a comment on the accepted answer, and should not have been made as a separate attempt to answer.

Comment: Just one thing to add here, this works great however you should be reading the size of the buffer - 1 bytes. And to view it properly I wouldn't use a newline in that print statement. Should look like this:`bytes = recv(sockfd, response, 1023, 0)`

Comment: Here the data received would be a raw response, how do we parse the message/content alone?

Answer (score 6):

Handle added.
Added Host header.
Added linux / windows support, tested (XP,WIN7).
WARNING: ERROR : "segmentation fault" if no host,path or port as argument.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit, atoi, malloc, free */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#ifdef __linux__ 
    #include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
    #include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */
    #include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#elif _WIN32
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#else

#endif

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int i;
    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int bytes, sent, received, total, message_size;
    char *message, response[4096];
    int portno = atoi(argv[2])>0?atoi(argv[2]):80;
    char *host = strlen(argv[1])>0?argv[1]:"localhost";
    char *path = strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/";
    if (argc < 5) { puts("Parameters: <host> <port> <method> <path> [<data> [<headers>]]"); exit(0); }
    /* How big is the message? */
    message_size=0;
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
                printf("Process 1\n");
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n");        /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                         /* path           */
        message_size+=strlen(path);                         /* headers        */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                     /* query string   */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
    }
    else
    {
                printf("Process 2\n");
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                         /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(path);                            /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen("Content-Length: %d\r\n")+10; /* content length */
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                     /* body           */
    }
            printf("Allocating...\n");
    /* allocate space for the message */
    message=malloc(message_size);

    /* fill in the parameters */
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message,"%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",               /* method         */
                path,                                          /* path           */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?"?":"",                      /* ?              */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?argv[5]:"",host);            /* query string   */
        else
            sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",               /* method         */
                path,host);                                    /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n",
            strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"POST",                  /* method         */
            path,host);                                        /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Content-Length: %d\r\n",(int)strlen(argv[5]));
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */
        if(argc>5)
            strcat(message,argv[5]);                           /* body           */
    }
    printf("Processed\n");
    /* What are we going to send? */
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);
        /* lookup the ip address */

    total = strlen(message);
    /* create the socket */
    #ifdef _WIN32
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s;

printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

printf("Initialised.\n");

//Create a socket
if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}

printf("Socket created.\n");

server = gethostbyname(host);
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server->h_addr);
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);
//Connect to remote server
if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    printf("connect failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected");
if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    printf("Send failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}
puts("Data Send\n");

//Receive a reply from the server
if((received = recv(s , response , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("recv failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
}

puts("Reply received\n");

//Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
response[received] = '\0';
puts(response);

closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
    #endif
    #ifdef __linux__ 
    int sockfd;
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");
        /* fill in the structure */
        memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
        memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);
                /* connect the socket */
        if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
            error("ERROR connecting");
                /* send the request */

    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);
    /* receive the response */
    memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    printf("Response: \n");
    do {
       printf("%s", response);
       memset(response, 0, sizeof(response));
       bytes = recv(sockfd, response, 1024, 0);
        if (bytes < 0)
           printf("ERROR reading response from socket");
       if (bytes == 0)
           break;
       received+=bytes;
    } while (1);

    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);
    #endif


    free(message);

    return 0;
}
```