# How to receive HTTP GET and POST requests in C socket program?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, cookies

I am trying to create a small C socket server. The server sends out the HTTP/HTML responses fine enough. But the clients would be sending it HTML requests and clients can be different devices - mobile apps, browsers etc. I need to log the requests about which type of devices are requesting what.

I happen to know that browser usually sends cookies and its user-agent info to the server as well and I want my server to be able to record the cookie and user-agent strings as well.

So how do I enable the reading of HTTP headers in my C/C++ server?

Comment: Look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response

Comment: Why not use php instead?

Comment: @Abhi The server has to be in C for performance reasons and can get lot of requests. The requirement is pretty simply for now. Also, the server might have to be embedded into some kind of device later (not sure about that).

Comment: Maybe start somewhere like here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039 , and then attempt to code what you need? (As I understand you already have the socket part working)

Comment: SO it still does not tell me how to read the entire GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do was essentially read from the socket. So using recv, the problem was solved. I was thinking complex while the solution was simple.