# C socket http post slower than curl

Tags: c, sockets, curl

I use Jerry's code [from this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response) in a context where the response is very short, to read a sensor with an esp8266 module. And I get a response after a delay of about 4 seconds. Yet with CURL command like: curl myip/?myQuery, I get the answer in less than a second.

Can someone explain to me why ?

Comment: No, no one can explain details of the server's behavior without details of its implementation.  I *speculate*, however, that the difference relates to the fact that Jerry's code emits a malformed HTTP request.  Well-formed HTTP request lines are terminated by carriage-return / line-feed *pairs* (`\r\n`), but Jerry's code uses bare line feeds.  The server might therefore wait for a time, expecting the rest of the message, before ultimately falling back to an error-handling strategy that happens to interpret the message as intended.

Comment: Thank you John, you are right, it was just the \r\n missing. The answer is instantaneous with it.