# CEF framework sending http request before close

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded, application-shutdown

I want to shut down server on window close (CEFsimple close) by sending http request to localhost:5000/shutdown.
I belive this should do the job

```
 browser->GetMainFrame()->LoadURL("http://127.0.0.1:5000/shutdown/");
```

So, where is the right place to do that? I have tried with functions like DoClose() and OnBeforeClose()...

Answer (score 1):

Making a `LoadURL` request when the browser is about to close is not guaranteed to succeed, due to the asynchronous nature of Chromium.

I would suggest you to use another library just for that purpose, which can be:

- [libcurl (wrapped in curlpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1112084/833188)
- [sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22135885/833188)

You have to make your HTTP request inside

```
void OnBeforeClose(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser);
```

method, which you have to implement after subclassing `SimpleHandler` from `CefLifeSpanHandler` and adding also

```
CefRefPtr<CefLifeSpanHandler> SimpleHandler::GetLifeSpanHandler() { return this; }
```

Comment: I am new to CEF and Chromium.  It seems like CEF could be run in single thread mode according to [this](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=270), no?

Comment: Not sure current CEF3 still supports that mode (quite obsolete)