# get external IP address through a c function

Tags: c, networking

I have two questions...

1.)Is it possible to get my external IP address with a c  function?

2.) If a device is listen() to a port (with struct sockaddr_in servAddr;
servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);) 
would the external IP address be the IP address to connect() from another  device ?

Comment: What if the system have *multiple* "external IP addresses"? Many systems today can have multiple interface-cards. The only reliable way is to already have a connection, and call `getsockname` on the connected socket to see what interface IP address the connection is using. Also `INADDR_ANY` means to listen to *all* interfaces, local or external, no matter how many.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get my external IP address with a c function?

This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). The short answer to your question, is "no".

The chances are if you are trying to get an external IP address it is because you are behind a nat and you want to run a server. Assuming you know what [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) is and can set it up on your nat box, you'll need to know your external IP address so you can actually connect to your server.

There are a number of public services that you can use to get your external IP address. One idea is to set up free [dynamic dns](http://www.noip.com/free). Another idea is to fetch your external IP from a service on the internet.

If you send an HTTP get request to http://ip-api.com/json, you'll get [back](http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) a json structure that you can parse:

```
A successful request will return, by default, the following:

{
    "status": "success",
    "country": "COUNTRY",
    "countryCode": "COUNTRY CODE",
    "region": "REGION CODE",
    "regionName": "REGION NAME",
    "city": "CITY",
    "zip": "ZIP CODE",
    "lat": LATITUDE,
    "lon": LONGITUDE,
    "timezone": "TIME ZONE",
    "isp": "ISP NAME",
    "org": "ORGANIZATION NAME",
    "as": "AS NUMBER / NAME",
    "query": "IP ADDRESS USED FOR QUERY"
}
```

C isn't the best language for this. A python implementation could be:

```
import urllib2,json
j=json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://ip-api.com/json'))
print(j['query'])
```

If you really want to hand code this in C, then take a look at Jerry's excellent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22135885/5058676) on writing a small program to do an HTTP get/post. You'll also want to look at some of the C json parsers on [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

> If a device is listen() to a port (with struct sockaddr_in servAddr; servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);) would the external IP address be the IP address to connect() from another device ?

Yes, if the other device is on the far side of your nat box and you have port forwarding set up.