# C Lang: REST Client

Tags: c

Trying to learn C language by using it for my day-today tasks.

1. I have a REST api created using Python-Flask
2. It is hosted on IIS 8.5 which is on Windows Server 2012 R2
3. The api is accessible through IP address and can be consumed through postman or curl (i have tested it)

I have created rest client in C following the Microsoft document at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646207/rest-client-in-c

I have made following changes to code  -

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024
#define DEFAULT_PORT "5000" //Port on which rest api is available

const char *sendbuf = "GET /abc/def HTTP/1.1"; //GET call with the route
```

When I print the request and response, I get the following -

```
The ip address is 10.16.186.23
GET /abc/def HTTP/1.1
Bytes Sent: 22
Bytes received: 490
Buffer Received: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 04:26:02 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 311

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
0
Connection closed
```

On the windows server, the HTTP calls are logged in two locations.

F:\inetpub\logfiles: The logfile logs all the HTTP call which are sent to IIS. When I call the rest api from Chrome or Curl, I can see the calls getting listed

C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR>: I believe this lists all those HTTP call which is not sent to IIS. The call initiated from C lang is appended in this log.

```
2020-05-14 03:40:10 10.1.66.191 58769 10.16.186.23 5000 HTTP/1.1 GET /abc/def 400 - Hostname -
2020-05-14 03:41:16 10.1.66.191 58784 10.16.186.23 5000 HTTP/1.1 GET /abc/def 400 - Hostname -
2020-05-14 03:44:52 10.1.66.191 58805 10.16.186.23 5000 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2020-05-14 03:48:00 10.1.66.191 59029 10.16.186.23 5000 - GET /abc/def 400 - BadRequest -
2020-05-14 03:49:01 10.1.66.191 59045 10.16.186.23 5000 - GET /abc/def 400 - BadRequest -
2020-05-14 03:50:40 10.1.66.191 59149 10.16.186.23 5000 - GET /abc/def 400 - BadRequest -
```

I checked 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/820729/error-logging-in-http-apis, it lists the reason

> "A parse error occurred while processing a Hostname."
>    and 
>   "A parse error occurred while processing a request."

Any idea what could be issue? Please note, I have tested the same code by hosting the flask service on localhost. C program successfully returned the response.

Comment: When you compare your requests with requests you made using Chrome or curl, what is different? Did you notice that the requests in the linked question contains some `"\r\n"` at the end?

Comment: Where is the `Host` header? That is the one header that is required by HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As pointed out in the comments [HTTP1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-19.6.1.1) requires the Host header

   > - A client that sends an HTTP/1.1 request MUST send a Host header.
2. Additionally you need to use CRLF as header delimiter `\r\n`
3. The header part is separated by an extra CRLF from the request body.

Hence, this should work:

```
const char *sendbuf = "GET /abc/def HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n"
```