# Multi-part file send example with C

Tags: c, sockets, multipartform-data

I try to write C code for sending 1 compressed file to server in HTTP POST multipart request with socket connection. I can't find on Net some multipart example for C language, could please somebody give an example? Thanks!

Comment: An example with libcurl: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html but this question is really too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Give more information about problem. First try google

Comment: @Federico thanks, I need example with sockets <sys/socket.h>

Comment: @EsmaeelE I need to write Post request like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response , but I need to do it as multipart I mean to add file data , headers and etc.