# Trying to send a POST request to local server with C

Tags: php, c, sockets, http, winsock

I am currently trying to send a full `POST` request with C to my local server where my PHP page will consume the request and `INSERT` the request into the database.

If I use the form I created to insert into the database, it works perfect.

But I'm trying to do the same `POST` request but in C to `INSERT INTO` the database. I'm not sure how to make the `POST` request. I intercepted the request with Burp so I know the request will be perfect and work. I'm just not sure how to implement it in my C program.

I have included my current C code to send the HTTP `POST` request.

I get a good reply, but nothing inserts into the database

```
/*
Create a TCP socket
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library


int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    int recv_size;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    printf("Socket created.\n");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected");


    char* str2;
    char* str3;
    char* str5;
    char* str20;

    str2 = "POST /project2/public/addJoke.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    str3 = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
    str20= "Content-Length: 12\r\n\r\n";
    str5 = "joketext=ctest&jokedate=2018-01-01";

    char * message2 = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str2)+ strlen(str3)+ strlen(str5) + strlen(str20));

    strcpy(message2,str2);
    strcat(message2,str3);
    strcat(message2,str20);
    strcat(message2,str5);




    if( send(s , message2 , strlen(message2) , 0) < 0)

    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;

    }
    puts("Data Send\n");

    //Receive a reply from the server
    if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    puts("Reply received\n");

    //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
    server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
    puts(server_reply);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my PHP file that receives the request.

```
if(isset($_POST['joketext'])){

try{

include __DIR__ . '/../includes/databaseconnection.php';

$title = 'Good Connection';

$sql = 'INSERT INTO jokes.jokes_tbl SET
joketext = :joketext,
jokedate = CURDATE(),
authorid = :authorid';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':joketext', $_POST['joketext']);
$stmt->bindValue(':authorid', $_POST['authorid']);
$stmt->execute();

header('location: jokeslist.php');

}catch(PDOException $err){
$title = 'Bad Connection';
$output = 'Bad Connection' . 
$err->getMessage() . ' in ' . 
$err->getFile() . ':' . $err->getLine(); 
}
}else{
 ob_start();
include __DIR__ . '/../templates/addJoke.html.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
}
include __DIR__ . '/../templates/layout.html.php';
```

Comment: Oh, what happened to the markup?

Comment: If you're asking how to send a POST requesting using C and Berkeley sockets, did you try [searching on this very site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response) ?

Answer (score 2):

> I intercepted the request with Burp so **I know the request will be perfect and work**.

Only it's not:

```
    message = "POST /project2/public/addJoke.php HTTP/1.1
...
upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
joketext=test200&authorid=1"
```

With some basic understanding of HTTP one can see that there is no marker which ends the HTTP header and starts the HTTP body, i.e. an empty line between header and body is missing. This means that `joketext=test200&authorid=1` is treated by the server as part of the header (albeit with invalid syntax) and that since no end-of-header marker is used the header is considered incomplete and thus also no body is detected.  Second problem is that the line end you use is probably `\n` and not `\r\n` as it should be.

Also, you are assuming that `send` will send everything in the buffer and only check for errors:

```
   if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
```

Only, `send` does not have such a guarantee. Instead you need to check the return value for the number of bytes actually send and do another `send` with any remaining (unsent) data. For small buffers like this you'll probably only need a single `send` but for larger buffers you will run into problems.

In general: HTTP is way more complex than you might think from barely looking at some HTTP requests. There is standard for a reason and anybody coding HTTP directly should study and understand the standard. Looking at a few requests as example is not sufficient, especially if one fails to look closely enough and is thus missing details of the white space line new lines, i.e. where it belongs and what the white space is made of.

EDIT: it looks like the OP has heavily edited the code in the question which now results in new problems:

```
str2 = "POST /project2/public/addJoke.php HTTP/1.0\r\n";
str3 = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
str20= "Content-Length: 12\r\n\r\n";
str5 = "joketext=ctest&jokedate=2018-01-01";
```

Obviously the length of 12 given in `str20` does not match the length of the actual body in `str5` which is 34. And, the formular expects a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `text/plain`. Both things were correct in the original question but are now wrong. Therefore I will again repeat my  above recommendation: *"...  anybody coding HTTP directly should study and understand the standard. Looking at a few requests as example is not sufficient..."*

Comment: Hi Steffen, Im managing to now get a successful reply from the server using a POST request, just cannot insert into database.

Comment: @JackWilson: Your original question was fully answered but you've made  changes to your code after the answer and introduced new problems. Please stop such editing which essentially makes your question a moving target which changes its meaning and instead ask a new question.