# How to send get request to a specific website using C?

Tags: php, c

We created a website connected to MYSQL database, and trying to reach the website (Insert items into database) using PHP API from this URL multiprotogw.000webhostapp.com/iot/insert.php?temp=30&hum=20

We found this code at [Simple C example of doing an HTTP POST and consuming the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response/22135885) 
and tried to send a GET request with through running it and including our web-page

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit, atoi, malloc, free */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;

    /* first where are we going to send it? */
    int portno = atoi(argv[2])>0?atoi(argv[2]):80;
    char *host = strlen(argv[1])>0?argv[1]:"localhost";

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total, message_size;
    char *message, response[4096];

    if (argc < 5) { puts("Parameters: <host> <port> <method> <path> [<data> [<headers>]]"); exit(0); }

    /* How big is the message? */
    message_size=0;
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\n");        /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                         /* path           */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[4]);                         /* headers        */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                     /* query string   */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
    }
    else
    {
        message_size+=strlen("%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n");
        message_size+=strlen(argv[3]);                         /* method         */
        message_size+=strlen(argv[4]);                         /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            message_size+=strlen(argv[i])+strlen("\r\n");
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen("Content-Length: %d\r\n")+10; /* content length */
        message_size+=strlen("\r\n");                          /* blank line     */
        if(argc>5)
            message_size+=strlen(argv[5]);                     /* body           */
    }

    /* allocate space for the message */
    message=malloc(message_size);

    /* fill in the parameters */
    if(!strcmp(argv[3],"GET"))
    {
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message,"%s %s%s%s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",               /* method         */
                strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/",                 /* path           */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?"?":"",                      /* ?              */
                strlen(argv[5])>0?argv[5]:"");                 /* query string   */
        else
            sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
                strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"GET",               /* method         */
                strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/");                /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */
    }
    else
    {
        sprintf(message,"%s %s HTTP/1.0\r\n",
            strlen(argv[3])>0?argv[3]:"POST",                  /* method         */
            strlen(argv[4])>0?argv[4]:"/");                    /* path           */
        for(i=6;i<argc;i++)                                    /* headers        */
            {strcat(message,argv[i]);strcat(message,"\r\n");}
        if(argc>5)
            sprintf(message+strlen(message),"Content-Length: %d\r\n",strlen(argv[5]));
        strcat(message,"\r\n");                                /* blank line     */
        if(argc>5)
            strcat(message,argv[5]);                           /* body           */
    }

    /* What are we going to send? */
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    /* send the request */
    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total);

    /* receive the response */
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response+received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while (received < total);

    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* process response */
    printf("Response:\n%s\n",response);

    free(message);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code with these parameters:

```
./a.out multiprotogw.000webhostapp.com 80 GET /iot/insert.php "temp=47&hum=83"
```

The output is:

```
Request:
GET /iot/insert.php?temp=47&hum=83 HTTP/1.0


Response:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Sun, 09 Jun 2019 22:12:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Server: awex
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-ID: 4339445424fa46df63c72689bd12f01c

<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your PHP script seems to working correctly when accessed directly through the browser with http://multiprotogw.000webhostapp.com/iot/insert.php?temp=47&hum=83 . The 500 error could mean a lot of things, you would need to check the server logs for any errors.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: the problem is how to over come this 500 error so we can send GET request to this URL: http://multiprotogw.000webhostapp.com/iot/insert.php?temp=47&hum=83  @Deanie

Comment: "*How to send get request to a specific website*" [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is your friend.

Comment: No, he is not @alk

Answer (score 0):

Most modern web servers will require that you send a valid HTTP/1.1 request, containing *at a minimum* a `Host:` header to indicate what web site you are making a request to. The correct format for such a request is:

```
METHOD /path HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: example.com\r\n
\r\n
```