# How to send GET request to http/https website using sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, get

I want to download the content of webpage .
When i am making get request to example.com , I am able make the connection .

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    //Stream sockets and rcv()
    
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd;
    
    char buf[2056];
    int byte_count;
    
    //get host info, make socket and connect it
    memset(&hints, 0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("example.com","80", &hints, &res);
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    printf("Connected!\n");
    char *header = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n";
    send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
    printf("GET Sent...\n");
    //all right ! now that we're connected, we can receive some data!
    byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf)-1,0); // <-- -1 to leave room for a null terminator
    buf[byte_count] = 0; // <-- add the null terminator
    printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
    printf("%s",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

But if in place of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) if i use http://info.cern.ch/ or http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/lectures/newton.pdf (to download the pdf) i get segmentation fault (with both port numbers 80 and 443) .

Code that doesn't work :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    //Stream sockets and rcv()
    
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd;
    
    char buf[2056];
    int byte_count;
    
    //get host info, make socket and connect it
    memset(&hints, 0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/lectures/newton.pdf","80", &hints, &res);
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    printf("Connected!\n");
    char *header = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/lectures/newton.pdf\r\n\r\n";
    send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
    printf("GET Sent...\n");
    //all right ! now that we're connected, we can receive some data!
    byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf)-1,0); // <-- -1 to leave room for a null terminator
    buf[byte_count] = 0; // <-- add the null terminator
    printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
    printf("%s",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a library like libcurl instead of trying to roll your own HTTP client.

Comment: Please show the exact code that **doesn't** work.

Comment: You MUST correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like socket(), connect(), send() and recv().

Comment: @Shawn I am trying to do without libcurl

Comment: @prog-fh I have added the code that does not work

Comment: @MartinJames when i am doing     sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol); then segmentation fault is happening . So i infer from it that previous line     getaddrinfo("http://galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu/lectures/newton.pdf","80", &hints, &res); is not able to work . I don't know how to correct it . It's easily happening with libcurl but i want to do without it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getaddrinfo()` and `Host:` (in the header) should specify the hostname (not the full URI).

In your example this is `galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu`.

Because you don't check the result of `getaddrinfo()`, you don't detect that the `res` pointer is not correctly initialised in case of failure.
Then, using the members of the pointed-to struct produces a segmentation-violation.

The request-header should be something like

```
"GET /lectures/newton.pdf HTTP/1.1\r\n"
"Host: galileoandeinstein.physics.virginia.edu\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n"
"\r\n"
```

The `Connection: close` is not mandatory but will ease your simple experiment.

In order to experiment with HTTPS, [this example](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) could be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks . After correctly writing domain name and request-header it's working for most of the http websites . However whenever i am trying to download https website then it's giving not able to do it .  Let's say i am trying to download https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page  then it's not showing error but not able to download it . I have attached the code link https://pastebin.com/ZXUPzDYA . It's same as in question but just i am using https website.

Comment: @DanielWayne HTTPS is HTTP via SSL, so you need some SSL utilities that perform encryption/decryption over the TCP connection.

Comment: Could you provide some links/resources for that . One of good resources i found : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011930/c-to-perform-https-requests-with-openssl

Comment: Where i can master these stuffs ? Any specific book or link which explains all these things using examples in C language ?

Comment: @DanielWayne [This site](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Main_Page) contains documentation and examples.