# C++ discord webhook http post

Tags: c++, discord, httprequest

is there a way to send a discord webhook message without external libraries? I searched a lot but couldn't find any, I hope someone can help.

Comment: Sure, just open a TCP socket connection to the server and send a correctly-formatted HTPP request.

Comment: Check the HTTP [examples](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp11_examples.html) with Asio.

Comment: ah, idk how tcp to send an http request, do you know any tutorial or anything that might help me

Comment: oh thank you @karastojko and Quimby

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077802/simple-c-example-of-doing-an-http-post-and-consuming-the-response) is all you need, just change the content.

Comment: definitely checking that out :thumbsup:

Comment: You will probably need HTTPS. You're strongly recommended to use a library at least for the S part (TLS).

Comment: why would you not want to use an external library? I would recommend looking into them for example: https://dpp.dev/classdpp_1_1webhook.html