# example of simple http/https request in c

Tags: c, rest, http, https, request

I try to make simple http and https request in c, for that I follow this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22135885/21597560), but it works with the example, but it doesn't work with https rest api, for example: [here](https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees)

I would like to have an example of how I can make an https and http request from scratch, without using external libraries like libcurl.

Comment: HTTPS is just HTTP over TLS/SSL. You almost **have to use external libraries for the SSL part**, it would take you forever to write a TLS client from scratch. You can use, for example, the openssl library to create the TLS socket. After that, just follow the http example but using the TLS socket instead of the plain socket.

Comment: How I can make a HTTP over TLS/SSL, please give me a code example. @PresidentJamesK.Polk