# How to make a C program issue an HTTP request and read the response?

Tags: c, http

I need a Raspberry Pi - which I am coding in C - to be able to communicate with an HTTP server, similar to how a dynamic web page can use AJAX to interact with its origin server.

How do I do that? Do I call [system()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) with a URL as parameter?

Or it there some other way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean a HTTP request? AJAX is javascript specific

Comment: Isn’t *ajax* term related with javascript ecosystem? In C language there must be some other terms to refer communication with outside, imho.

Comment: AJAX is a *programming technique* supporting dynamic web pages, involving asynchronously communicating XML messages with the origin server under control of Javascript.  I've read that Google, one of the pioneers in this area, disfavors the term "AJAX", preferring instead to just say "Javascript".  A C program can behave similarly, but it's unclear what degree of similarity you require, or how the the web-application concepts around which the technique is built map to your C program and its environment.

Comment: I want my C prohram to do what a JS program would normally do - send an HTTP request and get a reply.

Comment: The "J" is not the only distinction between AJAX and what you now seem to want, nor even the most important one.  There are *numerous* ways for C programs to make requests to HTTP servers and receive their responses, and most of them have very few of the characteristics of AJAX.  I have edited the question to further clarify.  Even so, the question is still extremely broad.

Comment: Thanks for the help, John. Can you please post an answer or comment with one of those numerous ways? Preferably the simplest. HTTP GET will do. In fact, I just realized that I don't even need a reply in this case, not even to check the return code.

Comment: I ought to have used a different search term - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208299/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-in-c-without-libcurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simplest way would be to use a `system()` call with curl. For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("curl http://example.com/");
}
```

This will send a `GET` request to example.com and print the output. Depending on your application, that might be enough. (See the [manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) for more options.)

However, actually capturing the output and doing error handling will be more difficult than if you'd used a C library like curl.

Here's an example of how to use curl-the-library: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but I wouldn't equate it with AJAX.  You *could* do something AJAX-like with `libcurl`, but there's more to AJAX than just issuing requests and receiving responses.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry for answering the question instead of arguing with the asker.

Comment: I don't see how you can be confident that you *have* answered the question.  I'm inclined to think you haven't, but the question is not clear enough to be sure.

Comment: That works for me. It's what I expected to have to do (I have updated the question). Of course, I also want to read the reply, but know how to do that. @Nick, do I have to use curl? I thought that was a PHP thing, but don't have experience of it.   Btw, I upvoted, to cancel the downvote

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208299/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-in-c-without-libcurl

Comment: @Mawg You don't *have* to use curl. The HTTP protocol is pretty simple, and if you're just making a GET request to a single URL, you can avoid using any libraries. (As question you found shows.) If you want to make a POST request, or use cookies, or HTTPS, that's complicated enough that I'd use a library (such as curl) to do it. `I thought that was a PHP thing` It is available in PHP, but it's not just a PHP thing.

Comment: Thanks (+1) It's all slowly coming back to me - sockets. I have only ever used raw sockets and sent datastreams, but figuring out `HTTP GET` shouldn't be too difficult.