# GET Request only gets empty string

Tags: c, http, get

I've been given an example C code, that sends user entered requests to a specified server and prints the responses. Now I should change the code, so that a HTTP Request is sent to http://www.stardrifter.org/cgi-bin/ref.cgi with a Referer header set. The request is successfully sent, but I only get empty strings in response.

I already tried to send minimal GET requests and also pasted working requests from Postman into the code, but I always only get an empty string as response. Also it actually takes quite a while until I receive a response, usually between 1 and 2 minutes.

This is my code so far. Establishing the connection seems to work fine but forming and sending the requests isn't doing what I'd expect:

```
#include <stdbool.h>     // use booleans in C
#include <stdlib.h>      // use common functions
#include <stdio.h>       // use input/output functions
#include <string.h>      // use string functions
#include <unistd.h>      // use POSIX functions

#include <sys/socket.h>  // use socket function
#include <netinet/in.h>  // use internet address datatypes
#include <arpa/inet.h>   // use inet_ntoa function
#include <netdb.h>       // use network database functions

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *hostname = "stardrifter.org";
    int port = 80;

    /** -- Setup connection -- */

    // Get server host information
    struct hostent *serverInfo = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (serverInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to get info for host '%s'!\n", hostname);
        return -1;
    }

    // Create TCP/IP socket
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        printf("Failed to create socket!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set address and port of server
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = serverInfo->h_addrtype;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    memcpy(&serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr, serverInfo->h_addr, serverInfo->h_length);

    // Connect to server
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to connect to server at %s:%d!\n",
               inet_ntoa(serverAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(serverAddr.sin_port));
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("Connected to server at %s:%d\n\n",
               inet_ntoa(serverAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(serverAddr.sin_port));
    }

    /** -- Main program -- */

    char buffer[1024];
    int len = 0;

    char *request = "GET /cgi-bin/ref.cgi HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.stardrifter.org\r\nReferer: I'm a Referer\r\n\r\n";

    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    strncpy(buffer, request, sizeof buffer - 1);

    // Send message to server
    if (send(sock, buffer, len, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to send message to server!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sent message to server: \"%s\"\n", buffer);
    }

    // Receive response from server
    printf("Waiting for response...\n");
    memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
    if (recv(sock, buffer, 1024, 0) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to receive response from server!\n");
    }

    // Print received response
    printf("Received response from server: \"%s\"\n", buffer);

    // Close socket
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect a valid HTTP Response with an html body, but my program only gives:

```
Connected to server at 69.164.214.143:80

Sent message to server: "GET /cgi-bin/ref.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: www.stardrifter.org
Referer: I'm a Referer

"
Waiting for response...
Received response from server: ""

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm not sure, if I really get this "" as response or if there is a smth. like a timeout and then he simply reads the empty buffer.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a full [mcve], including headers and the part where you open the connection.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Failed to create socket!\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error indication is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror( "your error message" )`  properly handles all of that

Comment: regarding: `printf("Failed to send message to server!\n");`  When a communication has failed, DO NOT continue with executing the code, as if the communication were successful.  Rather call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  Note: both `exit()` and EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the `stdlib.h` header file

Comment: Here is an example of [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208299/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-in-c-without-libcurl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending zero bytes:

```
char buffer[1024];
int len = 0;

char *request = "GET /cgi-bin/ref.cgi HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.stardrifter.org\r\nReferer: I'm a Referer\r\n\r\n";

memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
strncpy(buffer, request, sizeof buffer - 1);

// Send message to server
if (send(sock, buffer, len, 0) < 0) {
    printf("Failed to send message to server!\n");
} else {
    printf("Sent message to server: \"%s\"\n", buffer);
}
```

or

```
int len = 0;

...

if (send(sock, buffer, len, 0) < 0) {
...
```

Why are you copying the `request` to `buffer`?  This works:

```
ssize_t bytes_sent = send( sock, request, strlen( request ), 0 );
```

Both `send()` and `recv()` return the number of bytes sent or received.  They do the for good reasons.  You need to check that returned value and make sure it's **exactly** what you expect.

Also, the third argument to `send()` is a `size_t`, not an `int`.