# How to make a http get request using node without 'require'

Tags: node.js, http

This question is similar to the below question, but for Node.js e.g. version 8.11.1

[How to make an HTTP get request in C without libcurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208299/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-in-c-without-libcurl)

Are there any tricks using JS without the use of `require('http')` to make a simple `GET` request with headers and read response ?

Comment: Can you please explain why you do not want to use `require('http')` in the first place?

Comment: Its for a CTF challenge where I'm a bit restricted

Comment: So what is the challenge? Simply not use the `http` module?

Comment: Well, you can always open a tcp socket connection and implement the http protocol yourself ...

Comment: @madflow - challenge is to not use require at all not just http

Comment: Let me try to dig into http code to see if I can open raw tcp sockets without the use of require

Answer (score 2):

You can make an http request  without the `http` module in a node script, by using an underlying client on the operating system. This is not "pure" node.js - but is a pragmatic answer I guess.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('curl -v -i https://stackoverflow.com', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }

  if (stderr) {
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    return;
  }

  console.log(`stdout:\n${stdout}`);
});
```

Comment: This wouldn’t work since the question is on how to do this without a require

Answer (score 1):

What you would expect to use in such a case, is the raw [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Unfortunately Node.js does not provide XHR API as we know it from the Browser. Same goes with window.fetch() API. There are a few npm libraries out there ([node-xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)) to overcome this, and help with code reusability, but if you look into their source code, you'll see that internally they also have the `require('http')`.

So I'm not sure if what you want is possible. Of course, unless you dig inside the code of the `http` module and write your own version of it.